# With Bash or ZSH is there a way to use a wildcard to execute the same command for each script?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a directory with script files, say:

```
scripts/
       foo.sh
       script1.sh
       test.sh
       ... etc
```

and would like to execute each script like:

```
$ ./scripts/foo.sh start
$ ./scripts/script1.sh start
etc
```

without needing to know all the script filenames.

Is there a way to append `start` to them and execute? I've tried tab-completion as it's pretty good in ZSH, using `./scripts/*[TAB] start` with no luck, but I would imagine there's another way to do so, so it outputs:

```
$ ./scripts/foo.sh start ./scripts/script1.sh start
```

Or perhaps some other way to make it easier? I'd like to do so in the Terminal without an alias or function if possible, as these scripts are on a box I SSH to and shouldn't be modifying `*._profile` or `.*rc` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple loop:

```
for script in scripts/*.sh; do
    "$script" start
done
```

There's just one caveat: if there are no such `*.sh` files, you will get an error. A simple workaround for that is to check if `$script` is actually a file (and executable):

```
for script in scripts/*.sh; do
    [ -x "$script" ] && "$script" start
done
```

Note that this can be written on a single line, if that's what you're after for:

```
for script in scripts/*.sh; do [ -x "$script" ] && "$script" start; done
```

Comment: Was hoping for something with less typing, maybe some ZSH code completion magic, but of course a loop would work, and isn't too long, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible. On the other hand, this for loop is so simple, it will work even in older versions of Bash (and of course zsh too).

Comment: On second thought too, I forgot the SSH'd box probably doesn't have zsh anyways. So I think this is the approach I'd have to use, like you said for compatibility.

Comment: Use Zsh and write your pattern as `scripts/*.sh(N)` . If there are no matching files, you do not get an error and the loop is simply skipped.

Answer (score 3):

Zsh has some shorthand loops that bash doesn't:

```
for f (scripts/*.sh) "$f" start
```